# how to query data in nested map and array in firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array called "fields"
it is list of maps that contains map and strings
I wanna query for "عنوان" or "خانه فروشی" but it returning empty result
it tried this
but no result

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('items')
    .where('category',
                isEqualTo: FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(
                    '/cate/tweYUyMHTdWJWux1xjsh/subCategories/mA4iWPb56UAF8MczQqpb'))
    .where('fields', arrayContains: {'title': {'fa': 'عنوان'}}) //this lin I asking for
    .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // ...
  },
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore can query array items for exact equivalence, but not for partial matches.

So if you have the exact, complete value of the item in the array, you can use `arrayContains` to match on that. If you only have part of the item you can't.

The typical workaround is to add an additional array field to the document with just the information you want to query on, like:

```
field_titles: [
  { 'title': {en:'title', 'fa': 'عنوان' }} }
]
```

Or more likely:

```
field_title_fas: [
  'عنوان'
]
```

With that in place, you can perform the query on *that* array field.

Comment: I can't change database structure like that!
is there any way to handle that?

Comment: No there isn't. To allow the query you want against the database, modifying your data structure as I've shown is the only path forward. If you can't do that, the only alternative is to read all data and filter in your code.